# Is there any pattern for changing the state of the object on schedule?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

The situation is following:

- I need to keep a lot of objects (let's say `Food`) in database (in my case it's MySQL).
- Each object has a property `State` which is enumerable taking one of "FRESH", "STALE" or "SPOILED".
- Each object changes its state according some schedule. For instance, an object `Bottle of milk` is created with `FRESH` state, but after 2 days it becomes `STALE`, then after next 3 days it becomes `SPOILED`.

The question is: is there any pattern that allows me to control states of objects and change them accordingly? For instance, I can run some script every 30 minutes, select all the objects, inspect their states and change them. But this approach looks suboptimal, I'm trying to find out something better.

**Edit**
Running a routine each 30 minutes adds load to database (because each time I ned to select records for analysis). I'm trying to find a solution that:

1. makes minimum requests to RDBMS (MySQL in my case)
2. produces minimal lag between actual status change and a time a routine starts (running a routine each 30 minutes means some records will change their state with 30 minutes delay at most)
3. extendable, because there may be more states to be supported (that's why JB Nizet's answer won't work for me)

I could use some smart scheduler that keeps an ordered map like `timestamp -> [(object_id, next_state)]` in memory (up to 128G is available for this task).

Comment: "suboptimal"/"better" in terms of what?

Comment: I'm not sure if checking state of each object every 30 minutes (for example) using some scheduler is good idea. Thus, I'm looking for alternative options

Comment: "good" in terms of what? Talking about solution X being better than solution Y *does not make sense* in general. **Always specify** the context - what are your **criteria**. Time? Number of DB roundtrips? Frequency? Memory complexity? Storage size?

Comment: Running a routine each 30 minutes adds load to database (because each time I ned to select records for analysis). I'm trying to find a solution that: 

1) makes minimum requests to RDBMS (MySQL in my case) 
2) produces minimal lag between actual status change and a time a routine starts (running a routine each 30 minutes means some records will change their state with 30 minutes delay at most)

Comment: These are important details, you should include them in your question. Seems that JB Nizet's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), the state property does not need to be stored in the database.

In general, the design pattern for an entity that periodically does some clean-up, maintenance, etc. is called the *Agent* design pattern.

In your case:

```cpp
class FoodStateAgent
{
    void Run()  // called periodically from a Scheduler
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Agents usually work together with *Schedulers* - classes responsible for running specific actions on their defined deadline's.

Comment: At the end I ended up with Scheduler pattern :) But the sceduler is smart: basically, it's a Key-Value storage with TTL for each record. Once item is expired, the scheduler fires a task for agent.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store the state in the database. You should store the moment it becomes stale, and the moment it becomes spoiled.

That way, you don't need to ever change anything in the database.

To get items that are spoiled, you just need a query like

```
select * from item where now() >= spoileddate
```

To get items that are stale, you just need a query like

```
select * from item where now() >= staledate and now() < spoileddate
```

To get items that are fresh, you just need a query like

```
select * from item where now() < staledate
```

That, BTW, has another advantage: you can know the state of an item at any given time, and not just its current state. So if you get a phone call asking "I ate product xyz three days ago, am I safe?", you can answer.

Comment: Good idea! The only problem is that time interval between "FRESH" and "STALE" can be changed in runtime by some configuration. In case of such change I need to check all the objects and change their `staledate` and `spoileddate` accordingly.